# Using the -Like operator

Tags: powershell

I need to modify this script I've been working on to send an email alert if a directory we've found has "1970" in it's name. I am trying to accomplish this using the -Like operator but I can't get it work properly. I don't know if the issue is my usage of the operator, or perhaps the placement of the check, or something else entirely.

Some notes: I've edited out emails, and my SMTP server but I can confirm that line of code does work on it's own.

Here is what I've tried:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(0)
$logFile = "C:\STest\Log\log.txt"

#Throw a timestamp on the log file
Add-Content -Path $logFile "=======$(Get-Date)======="

#Get all of the paths for each camera
$paths = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Videos\" |Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

#for each path we found
foreach ($pa in $paths) {
    # Delete directories older than the $limit.
    $file = Get-ChildItem -Path $pa -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } 
    $file | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
    $file | Select -Expand FullName | Out-File $logFile -append
    if ($file.FullName -like '1970'){
        Send-MailMessage -to "Joe <Joe@Joe.com>" -from "Tod <Tod@tod.com>" -subject "1970 Found" -body "Testing" -SmtpServer mySMTPserver
    }
}
```

I've also tried:

```
if($file -like "1970"){ } 

if ($file.FullName -like "1970"){ } 

if ($file.FullName -like 1970) { }
```

Comment: try `-match` instead of `-like` ( the latter needs wildcars)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-like` is a wildcard operator.  To match '1970' anywhere in a string you need to add the wildcard `*` character at both ends:

```
PS C:\> 'something 1970 somethingelse' -like '*1970*'
True
```

If you want to match '1970' at the beginning of the string, omit the leading `*`.
To match '1970' at the end of the string, omit the trailing `*`.

Use the wildcard `?` character to match any single character, and the `[n-m]` 'globbing' wildcard syntax to match a range of characters.

See:

> [`Get-Help about_Wildcards`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847812.aspx)

for more information on using wildcard matches.

From a performance perspective, direct comparisons (`-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-gt`) are the fastest, followed by wildcard matches (`-like` and `-notlike`). Regex matching (`-match` and `-notmatch`) offers the most flexibility, but is also the slowest.

Comment: @Ansgar: Thanks for the edit (I screwed up the leading/trailing).  Any particular reason to trim off the performance considerations?

Comment: Weird, I don't recall having deleted (or even noticed) that paragraph when editing the answer. Restored.

Answer (score 1):

Try using replacing -like with -match

```
    if($file -match "1970"){ DO SOMETHING }
```

Comment: Excellent that works. But it appears to only send an email one time, even though there are multiple directories with "1970" in the name.

Comment: You are probably getting back a collection of files from Get-ChildItem, you need to loop those and perform the match.